# Describir a una persona como "arrastrado Pipián" en California, 1819

Tags: vocabulario, historia

En una carta a un colega, en el año 1819, el sacerdote Mariano Payeras caracterizó de "arrastrado Pipián" al Gobernador de la Alta California, Pablo Vicente de Solá.

Los dos eran españoles; a lo mejor Payeras eligió venir a la colonia y Solá fuera mandado por su servicio militar, que ofrece una interpretación posible del "arrastrado".

Percibo desde la RAE y mis dicionarios de jerga que un pipián o es una calabaza, o el guisado que se coce con aquella, o hasta la comida en general, pero no encuentro referencias a su posible significado aplicado a una persona.

Aquí va la traducción al inglés de Donald Cutter (Bellerophon Books, 1995). Es la única versión del texto que tengo; no provee contexto en español, solamente palabras por aquí y allá. Me da dudas y no sé si contar con su presentación:

> Now after [the attack on Monterey](http://mchsmuseum.com/bouchard.html) thanks are being given in the name of the King, our Lord, to the most useless and wretched nobody [*arrastrado Pipián*] because he is *de razón*, while they leave in eternal oblivion the priests who from nearby hastened to the defense of the homeland, the Indians who risked their lives and tranquility, and all the Missions which sacrificed everything for the success of such a just defense.

¿Qué quiso decir Payeras con esa frase?

Comment: Nótese que California no lleva tilde. ¿Hay algún motivo por el que lo escribiste? No edito por si su nombre antiguamente lo llevaba.

Comment: Sí fedorqui, muy bien, es que me confundí con el portugués en el cual sí se lleva.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según el DRAE, ["arrastrado"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3g9QCIj) significa "servil" o "rastrero"; también significa "adulador" en algunos lugares de América y parece que, antiguamente, significaba además "pícaro o "bribón". Me inclino a pensar que se refiere a lo primero.

En cuanto a ["pipián"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T7PF65K), el mismo DRAE recoge que, en El Salvador, significa "persona homosexual". [Otras fuentes](https://books.google.com/books?id=qr4uAAAAYAAJ&q=pipi%C3%A1n) indican que allí también se usa para referirse a un "hombre poco decidido". Es llamativo que Payeras use la expresión en California, y que esta acepción del término se limite en la actualidad, al parecer, a El Salvador. Puede que se refiera en realidad a la expresión del norte de México "ser pipián de todos los moles", de la que encontré muy pocas referencias: se usa "cuando una persona se acomoda en todos los niveles sociales y económicos, y que no existe un lugar donde no esté presente", según lo poco que se puede ver de *[Refranes norteños y sanos pensamientos](https://books.google.com/books?id=hSwsAAAAYAAJ&q=pipi%C3%A1n)*. Tendría sentido si nos constara que Payeras pensaba que el gobernador era acomodaticio, lo que no sería de extrañar si al decirle "arrastrado" lo trataba de servil.

Comment: Definición 4 en https://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/servil es él, Solá.  Nunca se casó. Ojala supieramos si los peninsulares o los mexicanos usaban entonces en el mismo sentido la palabra, pipián. CORDE ni contiene lo centroamericano de hoy, aunque aparece en muchos otros lugares.